# PHP Condition based on time (text changes color if last ping was x minutes ago)

Tags: php, conditional-statements, ping

I'm making a simple interface to monitor some devices remotely with a php interface.
I've written a small script that pings to my server and writes each ping in a log and displays the last one in a php page saying: "Last ping 10:24 pm"

I'd love to be able to change the color of the text depending on the last time the device pinged: for example: if it was less than 5 minutes ago : text is green. Between 10 and 5: orange. More than 10: Red.

How can I do it ?

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: show your code first?

Comment: assuming you're already done on parsing of how many x time ago, just use a condition on the coloring, simple if else if blah blah

Comment: $file = '';
$file .= $log['c_mainfolder'] . "/log/log.txt";
$data = file($file);
$line = $data[count($data)-1];
// echo $line;
$pieces = explode(" ", $line);
$lastping = $pieces[0]; // piece1
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('[j/M/Y:H:i:s]', $lastping);
$currentTime = time();


echo "<span class=\"label success\"> <i>Last Access : </i>";
echo $date->format('H:i - D d/m');

Comment: @ghost: I didn't do the parsing yet. I'm going to edit my question as it only displays time of the last ping

Comment: hello @Martin92 can you give an example value of `$line`?

Comment: @Ghost : here you are [03/Sep/2014:13:03:52] (log) NameOfDevice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use this get parse the date and give color to the text. Adjust the time so see the difference:

```
$line = '[09/Sep/2014:15:32:52] (log) NameOfDevice';
preg_match_all('^\[(.*?)\]^', $line, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$raw_date = $matches[1][0];

$log_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/M/Y:H:i:s', $raw_date);
$final_log_date = $log_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');


// handle ago
$now = new DateTime;
$ago = new DateTime($final_log_date);
$diff = $now->diff($ago);

$diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
$diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

$string = array('y' => 'year', 'm' => 'month', 'w' => 'week','d' => 'day', 'h' => 'hour','i' => 'minute', 's' => 'second',);
foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
    if ($diff->$k) {
        $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
    } else {
        unset($string[$k]);
    }
}
$string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);

// handle color
$minute = round(abs($now->getTimestamp() - $ago->getTimestamp()) / 60,2);
$color = 'black';

if($minute <= 5) {
    $color = 'green';
} elseif ($minute > 5 && $minute <= 10) {
    $color = 'orange';
} else {
    $color = 'red';
}

$time = implode(', ', $string) . ' ago';

echo "<span style='color: $color;'>$time</span>";
```